# Mostraer el contenido de un foreach ( $_SESSION) en un input

Tags: php, html

Amigos, tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php
    foreach ( $_SESSION[ "shopping_cart" ] as $product1 ) {
      $productosComprados = $product1[ "code" ];
      ?>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $productosComprados; ?>" id="" name="">
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Pero lo que necesito es de que todo lo que esta dentro de `$product1[ "code" ]` se mueste dentro de un input type text, asi por ejemplo:

```
<input type="text" value="000-001 000-002 000-003 000-004" id="" name="">
```

Comment: Solo por curiosidad, si pones `<input type="text" value="<?php implode(' ', array_column($_SESSION['shopping_cart'], 'code')) ?>">`. Te funciona?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías de tener la variable por fuera del for algo como:

```
<?php
  $productosComprados = "";
  foreach ( $_SESSION[ "shopping_cart" ] as $product1 ) {
    $productosComprados = $productosComprados . " " . $product1[ "code" ];
  }
?>
   <input type="text" value="<?php echo $productosComprados; ?>" id="" name="">
```